# C restrict with typedef

Tags: c, typedef, restrict-qualifier

i'm doing some code now and got some problem using restrict keyword.

```
typedef int* pt;

int foo(pt a, pt b)
{
 ... /* stuff */
}
```

What if I want to make a and b restricted? The code below failed:

```
typedef int* pt;

int foo(pt restrict a, pt restrict b)
{
 ... /* stuff */
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you need to be more precise what you mean by "The code below failed".

Comment: FWIW, your code compiles fine with GCC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a "restricted pointer to integer" `int * restrict p` not a "pointer to restricted integer" `restrict int *p` so you will need to make another typedef.  You can't "reach inside" the original one.

EDIT:  While it's true that you *can't* reach inside the typedef and the modifier will always apply at the top level, in this case it turns out that you *want* the `restrict` at the top level.  It's the inverse of what people usually run into with `const`:  `typedef char *char_ptr` means `const char_ptr` (or `char_ptr const`, they're equivalent) both mean "constant pointer to char" not "pointer to constant char" which is what people want.  (See also this SO thread: [C++ typedef interpretation of const pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253738/c-typedef-interpretation-of-const-pointers) )

So in this case I think `typedef int *pt` does mean that `restrict pt` means `int * restrict pt`.  It's pretty easy to verify because gcc will complain about "invalid use of 'restrict'" for `restrict int *x` but not for `restrict pt x`.

Comment: o god... i'm gonna need alot of hacks then

Comment: can you please clariy? Why wouldn't `pt restrict` denote the type `int *restrict` ? I think this answer is wrong.

Comment: @Johannes: assuming `restrict` "spreads" the same as `const`, you are right: `static_assert(std::is_same<const pt, int* const>::value, "foobar");` does not complain.

Comment: I tried to update this to be correct after it was accepted but problems were pointed out in the answer.  To those who would still downvote:  At least comment with your reasoning since it's still going to be at the top and might as well be updated to fix any problems!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you're compiling it using the C99 flag for your compiler. The `restrict` keyword doesn't exist in C89 C.

Comment: Do you mean ANSI C99 or ANSI C89?

Answer (score 1):

Having a quick look and reading this similar [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748818/c-c-restrict-type), the code would be, as the keyword 'restrict' is not reserved keyword in C++ compilers, as indicated by the accepted answer in the above linky, either `__restrict` or `__restricted__`, again, check your compiler...

```
typedef int* __restrict pt;

int foo(pt a, pt b)
{
 ... /* stuff */
}
```

Comment: I used your answer in [a question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43631062/2542702) and everyone is saying it's a very bad idea. Can you comment on my question?